# Is transition from scattering state to bound state, a quantum phase transition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-transition

Let's say there is a system with two particles with exchange potential $U(x)$ such that $\int U(x)dx > 0$. So there exists a critical potential strength $U_c>0$ [Brownstein et al. 2000](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.19389?casa_token=OD6ADaE-y7UAAAAA:YMMDU2j2xRui6x2luOjs-KTgWXuaCFu2n_uyg6kc0mWWLe6k64EU66BE3Yk8flnORDl2QvfoBVtV), where the particles will transit from a scattering state to a bound state. I have an intuition that this could be a quantum phase transition at $T=0$, if I adiabatically increase from region $U<U_c$ to $U>U_c$, but I lack the physical arguments. Can anyone explain, if possible site some references?

Comment: What is $U_c$ related to the exchange potential $U(x)$? and how can you change $U_c$?

Comment: @ytlu Think of it as a parameter, that we can change theoretically. For example, a finite well or a double well, whose potential strength can be changed as a parameter.

Comment: Two pints to be clarified: 1. How is $U_c$ appears in the function $U(x)$? I assumed that it is a parameter in the function $U(x)$, or an integration form of it. 2. How can you change this parameter in real world. There will relate to the nature of the process  - adiabatic.

Comment: @ytlu I cannot give you the exact form of the potential, but it is a rectangular potential, like potential well. So $U(x) = 0$ if $x<-a/2 \& x > a/2$ and $=U_0$ if $|x|<a/2$, where $U_0$ can be varied from 0 to any real value. Now there exists a critical $U_c$ and a real number where the system goes to a bound state.

Comment: @ytlu I am not sure how one can vary exchange potential adiabatically like mentioned above, this question is completely based on a thought experiment.